# How to create a Service Port in Client go

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am having trouble adding the Ports field in `ServiceSpec`. What am I doing wrong?

```golang
import (
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

    port := corev1.ServicePort{}
    port.Port = 8443
    ports := make(corev1.ServicePort, 1)

    service := &corev1.Service{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      "test-webhook-admissions",
            Namespace: "test",
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "test",
                "app.kubernetes.io/name":     "test",
                "control-plane":              "controller-manager",
            },
        },
        Spec: corev1.ServiceSpec{
            Ports:    ports, // Not working
            Selector: nil,
            //ClusterIP:                "",

        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
func GetLabels() map[string]string {

    return map[string]string{
        "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "test",
        "app.kubernetes.io/name":     "test",
        "control-plane":              "controller-manager",
    }

}


    service := &corev1.Service{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      "test-webhook-admissions",
            Namespace: namespace,
            Labels:    GetLabels(),
        },
        Spec: corev1.ServiceSpec{
            Ports: []corev1.ServicePort{
                {
                    Name:       "webhook",
                    Port:       8443,
                    TargetPort: intstr.FromInt(8443),
                    Protocol:   "TCP",
                },
            },
            Selector: GetLabels(),
        },
    }

    err := w.Client.Create(context.Background(), service)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you have to append the object port to your slice ports.